# Assembly stores to DATA segment not all showing up

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I got a question in my Computer Science Class to write in DATA SEGMENT from cell 0h to 100h and it's half working, it's overwrite every cell excluding EE to FF

```
Start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov si, 100h ; starting DATASEG
    mov cx, 0h ; counting 
    mov al, 0FFh ; Number setting in each segment

loop1: 
    mov [si],al
    dec si ; decrease location
    inc cx ; increase counting
    CMP cx,101h
    jne loop1
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Do you really want your data in the same location as your stack?

Comment: It would be simpler to use the pointer as your loop counter, instead of also using `CX` as a down-counter.  e.g. `cmp si, 100h` / `jbe loop1`  to re-enter your loop when si is in the range that you want.

Comment: To elaborate on my previous comment: remember that the stack grows _downward_. So if you start out with `sp=100h`, as soon as you start pushing anything onto the stack you'll be writing into the 00h..FFh area of the stack segment (which happens to be the same as the data segment in your case).

Comment: BTW, if you want it to run faster, store 2 bytes at a time, or even use `rep stosb` with `ES:DI` set correctly (which on modern CPUs has an optimized internal implementation (micro-code) that stores 16 or 32 bytes at a time).  Except when you're storing so close to `CS:IP`; that will trigger self-modifying-code machine clears.  I don't think you are actually overwriting your code, though, the hardware just doesn't like writing data that close to code.  (Totally irrelevant for performance, and I think DOSBOX emulates anyway, so no real CPU is running that machine code.)

Comment: I'd recommend copy/pasting your DOSBOX window contents as text, not an image.

Comment: To allow people to write a complete answer could you update your question with all of the assembler file contents. We want to see how you set up everything like the stack and data area. A complete assembly file would allow for a complete answer. I'm more curious to know how segments were set up that made SS=DS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @Michael has found the reason: `SS` = `DS`, and your `SP=100h`, so interrupt handlers will clobber the space below SP.  This is the end of the to `DS:00`.. `DS:100h` range that is getting overwritten.

Even the debugger itself may be partially intrusive and clobber memory below the debugged program's `SP` (e.g. when an `int3` instruction pushes exception-return info).  (You're running TurboDebugger inside DOSBOX, rather than using a debugger built-in to DOSBOX or BOCHS; that would let you debug fully non-intrusively, but timer interrupts would still clobber below SP when you don't have interrupts disabled).

So your code worked, but its results were overwritten by the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is what Peter Cordes posted (and you managed to not show the relevant code, which is causing the problem, the code in your question is correct, no problem there, but the initial data-segment and stack setup is wrong).

That's why good debugging questions on StackOverflow require [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

---

I just wanted to add, how you can achieve the same result with simpler 16b code, using `rep stos` pattern and `es:di` addressing:

```
    mov ax, @data
    mov es, ax
    xor di, di   ; es:di = start of DATASEG
    mov cx, 100h/2  ; number of "word" elements to write
    mov ax, 0FFFFh  ; number to set in each cell
    cld          ; just in case DF was not 0
    rep stosw    ; write 100h cells
    stosb        ; final 101h-st cell to cover whole 0000-0100 range
```

It will still demonstrate the same problem, as your stack will overwrite that part of data segment, but it will set the dataseg cells more efficiently.